# AllowAnonymousToPage using wildcards?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Is this possible? I want to do something like this but it seems impossible:

```
options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Data/**/Details");
```

But I can't get this to work.

Comment: What does you actually mean by "I can't get this to work." ? What are your expected and actual results? I can not reproduce the issue by the existing information , could  you share more details or a demo that can reproduce your issue ?

Comment: Meaning the function is not accepting wildcards. It ignores it. I just want to know how I can get it to accept wildcards. I don't think I need to explain what `AllowAnonymousToPage()` does.

Comment: Basically when I entered in this wild card, I expected it to allow anonymous to pages matching the given wildcard. But the app did not allow anonymous access to those pages.

Comment: I tried the `AllowAnonymousToPage` ,and it worked well. If you want us to help you debug the code to solve the problem, please share more code or a demo which could reproduce the issue .

Comment: Did you try it with wildcards?

Comment: Yes, if you want us to help you debug the code to solve the problem, please share more code or a demo which could reproduce the issue.